# error with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a very simple collection view, but somehow it keeps crashing. here is the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Reuse - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

and my codes:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseCellIdentifier = @"Reuse";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 95)];
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 45)];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 15)];
    name.text = @"user";

    return cell;
}
```

Help!!

Comment: Give cell identifier as "Reuse" inside Collection Reusable View section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you didn't declare your cell reuse identifier on your storyboard, do these steps:

**- select the cell on your storyboard**

[image]

**- Enter the reuse identifier into the "Collection Reusable view identifier", in your case enter "Reuse" there**

[image]

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 2):

use this  and if not set delegate. please your delegates.

Prior to calling the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method of the collection view, you must use this method or the `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier`: method to tell the collection view how to create a new cell of the given type. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the collection view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.

```
  [self.yourcollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

[image]

[apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:)

Answer (score 0):

check out this link..
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/.
Give the Identifier(Reuse) name and static NSString *reuseCellIdentifier = @"Reuse"(this name); should be same ..